# How do I develop a Windows Mobile application in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

How to make Windows Mobile application in Visual Studio 2008
What is the requirement for that.
What Sdk to download.

please reply on this.

Comment: It depends which version of Windows Mobile you wish to target and in which languages

Comment: And what version of Visual Studio you have.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you already installed the mobile development toolkit as part of visual studio installation. This is the first step. This provides option to create application for Windows mobile 5 and earlier phones. If it is not done, please run installation again and include these components.

You should then download the windows mobile 6 sdk refresh from 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en

Please note that the Professional and Standard SDK are for different target phones. More details are given below.

With the above download, you can create applications for Windows mobile version 6.

For Windows mobile 6.5 and 6.5.3 applications you have to additionally download 
[Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e) 
and Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Developer Tool Kit.

The following text from the first link explains the difference between Professional and Standard Edition:

> With Windows Mobile 6, we are revising
>   our SKU taxonomy and naming to better
>   align our brand and products with the
>   realities of today’s mobile device
>   marketplace. The historical
>   form-factor based distinction between
>   Windows Mobile powered Smartphone and
>   Windows Mobile powered Pocket PC Phone
>   Edition is blurring dramatically. We
>   want our taxonomies and terminology to
>   evolve to better reflect the evolution
>   of the mobile device industry.
>
> The list below summarizes the changes
>   and the SDK that must be used when
>   targeting the platforms (Previous
>   Categories = New Categories):
>
> 1. Windows Mobile for Smartphone = Windows Mobile Standard (download the
>      Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK)
> 2. Windows Mobile for Pocket PC = Windows Mobile Classic (download the
>      Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK)
> 3. Windows Mobile for Pocket PC Phone Edition = Windows Mobile
>      Professional (download the Windows
>      Mobile 6 Professional SDK)

PS: I could not post the hyperlink for 6.5.3 as a newbie I can't post more than two links. Please google to get the download link.